# How do I show a mapview and a listview on the same screen?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-maps

Usually I would just seperate out the activities but I want to show a screen that has a view text views, a list, and then a map view. I'm not sure how to go about doing that because I know the activity can only extend either listview or mapview.

I have one xml file like this we'll call it the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffff">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:textColor="@color/dark" android:text="Name"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/etName"></EditText>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:text="Add location"></Button>
    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and another xml file that is just a big map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapsView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="myapikey" />
```

The main activity inflates the first xml sheet with the list, but then how do I add the map to this? Do I nest a class that extends the map activity class and some how add the view?
This is what I was thinking

```
public class AddLocationActivity extends ListActivity{


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



}
public class ShowMap extends MapActivity{

            public ShowMap(){

             //maybe get the map.xml and add the view somehow?
             }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: why can't you extend MapActivity and use ListView as its member.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30644926/3871524
try this.. Its very HelpFul for me to display map in Listview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mkso commented, you do not need to extend from `ListActivity` to use a `ListView`, see [this for an example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example) (not the best, but what I could find quickly). Just create the layout how you want it, extend from `MapActivity` and use the `ListView` by calling `findViewById()`.