# How can I connect ListView to Google Map. I would like to select a location then change the map polylines and cameraposition

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Select Route'),
),
body: ListView(
children: [
ListTile(
leading: Icon(Icons.map),
title: Text('Origin: Calinan'),
subtitle: Text('Destination: Roxas'),
trailing: IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
onPressed: () {
Navigator.push(context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Map()));

```
              })),
      ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.map),
          title: Text('Map'),
          trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Map()));
              })),
      ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.map),
          title: Text('Map'),
          trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Map()));
              })),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Although ListView is a great way to display widgets in an orderly fashion, [as this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612709/13789971), you don't want to use Google Maps in ListView.